# Android How to setWeight of a RemoteView?

Tags: android, android-layout-weight, remoteview

I need to know the code that allow me to set the Weight of a RemoteView.

I tried with this code but this doesn't work:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.ll_notification, "setWeight", 12);
```

There is a way to do this?
Many thanks....

Answer (score -1):

I think RemoteView does not have a weight property.

I am not sure that is going to work but give it a try.

```
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews("", 0);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams tempLayoutParams =new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    tempLayoutParams.weight = 1.0f;

    LinearLayout tempLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext()):
    tempLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(tempLayoutParams);

    tempLinearLayout.addView(remoteViews);
```

Good luck.